# Does Leonardo DiCaprio fly on private jets?

Tags: climate-change, energy, energy-efficiency, leonardo-dicaprio

Does Leonardo DiCaprio fly on private jets?

Example claim: [Leonardo DiCaprio flies 8,000 miles in private jet to accept ‘green award'](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/leonardo-dicaprio-flies-8000-miles-in-private-jet-to-accept-green-award-a7042326.html)

> Oscar-winner Leonardo DiCaprio flew an additional 8,000 miles from
>   France to New York and back to accept an award on climate change.
>
> The actor suffered a massive blow on his carbon footprint when he took
>   one jet from the Cannes Film Festival to New York City to attend the
>   green awards ceremony, before hopping on board a second jet for a
>   fund-raising event back in Cannes the following evening.

and another example, [Hollywood hypocrite's global warming sermon](http://www.heraldsun.com.au/blogs/rita-panahi/hollywood-hypocrites-global-warming-sermon/news-story/b4cc2e4b6034c032998fb3c13e6df4a6)

> So, [Leonardo DiCaprio believes that climate change deniers should not
>   be allowed](http://insider.foxnews.com/2016/10/05/leonardo-dicaprio-climate-change-deniers-shouldnt-be-allowed-hold-public-office) to hold public office. Pretty rich coming from a man whose
>   jetsetting lifestyle seems him take dozens of flights annually,
>   including many on private jets.

Comment: @Alexander is it notable? See how often the claim is mentioned on Twitter. Is there reason to doubt? Yes, because climate change sceptics would be biased towards believing that activists themselves are hypocrites.

Comment: Would those objecting to use of a private jet be happier if he'd flown commercial?  Seems like anyone really interested in reducing CO2 emissions would have done it by telepresence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, he has flown on a private jet on at least a few occasions.

From [the WikiPedia on Leonardo DiCaprio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_DiCaprio):

> ... his use of private jets and superyachts has attracted criticism by some sections of the media.[[148]](http://www.smh.com.au/lifestyle/celebrity/private-sydney/oscars-2016-leonardo-dicaprios-climate-speech-at-odds-with-his-huge-carbon-footprint-20160301-gn81iw.html)[[149]](http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/cody-battershill/leonardo-dicaprio-activism_b_9025188.html)[[150]](http://nypost.com/2016/01/24/why-leo-dicaprio-is-just-another-climate-hypocrite/) In 2016, during a vacation in Cannes, France, he made a one-day visit to New York City by private jet to collect an environmental award. ... [[151]](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/05/21/leonardo-dicaprio-criticised-for-taking-private-jet-from-cannes/)

According to [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/05/21/leonardo-dicaprio-criticised-for-taking-private-jet-from-cannes/), the following statement was made about this specific instance:

> A source close to Mr DiCaprio said that the actor did not charter his own flights, but merely “hitched a ride with someone already flying back and to Cannes.
>
> "Hitching a ride was the only way he could make it in time for both events.”

On a side note, I would advise against drawing any conclusion about his carbon footprint based on this one data point. Estimating a carbon footprint requires taking into account many factors, including any positive impact they may have done to reduce their carbon footprint, which is something these sources do not attempt.